# Android - is there a way to tell which Intent the back button will take you to?

Tags: android

I am overwriting this function:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

But is there a way to tell which Intent or screen the back button is about to take the user to?

Comment: I don't understand. The activity already has an `onBackPressed()` callback that basically calls `finish()`. Anything other than "going back" will seem very unnatural to an Android user.

Comment: Please, don't touch the back button. It's a huge UX mess as it is, no need to complicate users life more. ( 
http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/21/back-means-back.html ; 
http://iamtherockstar.com/blog/2011/09/13/i-hate-android-back-button/ ; 
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/12/back-button-androids-achilles-heel.html
 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably better off adding information into the intent that launched your current activity.

Activity A

```
    Intent lIntent = new Intent();
    lIntent.putExtra( EXTRAS_ACTIVITY_KEY, ACTIVITY_IDENTIFIER );
    startActivitiy...
```

Activity B

```
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
           Intent lIntent = getIntent();
           if(lIntent.hasExtra(EXTRAS_ACTIVITY_KEY) &&
                   ACTIVITY_IDENTIFIER.equals(lIntent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_ACTIVITY_KEY)){
                   // Great we know that it was a Activity A...
                   ... your code here....
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve it from the Activity Stack using the ActivityManager.

Comment: sounds complicated. Would it be error prone? How would you do that?

Comment: Very error prone, but thats what you're trying to do. However; this shouldn't be necessary, it should be implied via UI presence where they are headed since in the end, YOU control how it works in **YOUR** Activities.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<CharSequence> theActivityTrace = getActivityTrace(null);
```

this the function that return a list of activities trace which are on stack and you can call the below method as above amd mAct is your current context.

```
public LinkedList<CharSequence> getActivityTrace(LinkedList<CharSequence> aTrace) {
    if (aTrace==null)
        aTrace = new LinkedList<CharSequence>();
    aTrace.add(mAct.getLocalClassName()+" ("+mAct.getTitle()+")");
    if (mAct.getCallingActivity()!=null)
        aTrace.add(mAct.getCallingActivity().toString()+" ("+mAct.getIntent().toString()+")");
    else if (mAct.getCallingPackage()!=null)
        aTrace.add(mAct.getCallingPackage().toString()+" ("+mAct.getIntent().toString()+")");

    return aTrace;
}
```